# PLSQL_Trigger if acct bal is negative_table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that prevents a negative or zero account balance. When I tested the trigger by updating the bal of an existing acct to negative, I got error: table ACCOUNT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. I don't understand what this means and how to get the trigger work.

```
Table Account(A#, CNAME, BNAME, BAL); PK=A#.
```

My code is as below:

```
create or replace trigger negbal
before insert or update on account
for each row
declare 
    v_bal NUMBER; 
begin
    select bal into v_bal from account where A#=:new.A#;
    if v_bal<=0 then
        raise_application_error (-20106, 'ACCT BAL MUST BE POSITIVE');
    end if;
end;
```

My test code is:

```
update ACCOUNT set BAL = -50 where A# = 7765;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that within a row level trigger you cannot refer to the table the table is on. As this trigger is a row level on table "ACCOUNT" it cannot reference the "ACCOUNT" table.

In this case you do not need a trigger, a check constraint will accomplish what you need. See the script below.

```
create table account (a# integer, bal number); 

insert into account (a#, bal) values (1, 25);

alter table account add (constraint acct_bal_gt_0 check (bal > 0));

insert into account (a#, bal) values (2, -50);   
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (ACCT_BAL_GT_0) violated

update  account 
    set bal = bal - 50  
  where a# = 1;  
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (ACCT_BAL_GT_0) violated

drop table account;
```

You cannot specify a specific message, but you can trap it in an EXCEPTION block if a specific message is required.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can I use pragma autonomous_transaction; ?

Comment: Using  pragma autonomous_transaction circumvents the mutating trigger error. But that is the wrong use of an autonomous transaction. As far as I'm concerned declaring an autonomous_transaction in a trigger is 99.999% of the time the same as using

Comment: OOPS, wrong key:  ... is the same as using "PRAGMA CREATE_BUG_HERE;"

Comment: @Belayer - there are a couple of valid uses of AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, such as logging.